# Detecting Infinite for loop

Tags: for-loop, ide

I am frequently writing infinite for loops example:

```c
for (i = 0; i < 5; ) {
   //some code here
   c++;  
   //++i may be missing
}
```

Are there automatic code analyzers that detect infinite loops?

Comment: Have you seen the updated answer?

Comment: Yes I have seen it. I have also heard that Android Studio has similar capabilities. I will try eclipse also to see what it can offer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have also found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2C_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 3):

There are certain analyzers in the IDE that can assist with infinite loop detection. However, properly recognizing an infinite process or chain of code before or even during its execution is paradoxical.

This is known as the "[Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)"

**Update**

All [JetBrain IDEs](https://www.jetbrains.com) have a built in feature that tries to detect infinite loops. It can be found in:

> *Preferences --> Inspections --> C/C++ --> Data Flow Analysis --> Endless loop*

Comment: I am just looking for something simpler: detecting the for loop extent, the name of the iteration variable and whether it is incremented (e.g. ++i). I could try and implement a parser myself but I think there is a simpler solution somewhere.